# Funcion para invertir cadena en Python

Tags: python

```
 def cadena(txt):
 if len(txt) ==0:
 return txt

 else:
 return cadena(txt[1:] + txt[0])

 txt = input()
 cadena(txt)
```

Deseo que me sugieran que estoy haciendo mal porque me da RecursionError, y que deberia corregir o agregar para que el código me funcione e invierta cualquier cadena que se ingrese y se imprima de esta manera, por ejemplo al ingresar BARCELONA:

A
N
O
L
E
C
R
A
B

Comment: Este codigo está mal indentado y no va a funcionar. Así lo estás probando?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es un simple detalle. Cuando haces

```
return cadena(txt[1:] + txt[0])
```

estas llamandote recursivamente con una cadena de igual largo que la original, pero corrida en una posición.

La forma correcta es

```
return cadena(txt[1:]) + txt[0]
```

El valor a retornar resulta de la llamada recursiva pasando una cadena recortada mas ese caracter que se recortó.

**Demo**

```
def cadena(txt):
    if len(txt) == 0:
        return txt
    else:
        return cadena(txt[1:]) + txt[0]

txt = "Barcelona"
print(cadena(txt))
```

produce:

```
anolecraB

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: otra forma corta  seria `return txt[::-1]`

Comment: Gracias tenia que mover el parentesis antes de la concatenacion y no despues. Ya resolvi el problema.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías cortar la cadena, si no especificas el inicio ni el fin solo el step(-1), así la cadena se recorrerá del final al inicio.

```
return(txt[::-1])
```

Y así quedaría aplicado:

```
def cadena(txt):
if len(txt) == 0:
    return txt

else: 
    return(txt[::-1])
```

Comment: Gracias pero yo deseaba hacerlo mediante recursion. Pero es otra manera que se puede hacer.

Comment: Basta con `def cadena(txt): return txt[::-1]`